# How can we call Mathematica functions from another server using the `wolframscript` Python library?

Tags: programming, scripting, mathlink-or-wstp, python, remote-access

How can we use the [`wolframclient`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) Python library to call Mathematica functions when Mathematica is running in an another server?

For example, if we have Mathematica running locally we can do as following:

```
from wolframclient.language import wlexpr
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with WolframLanguageSession() as session:
        code = 'N[Zeta[2]]'
        expression = wlexpr(code)
        
        result = session.evaluate(expression)

        print(result)
```

the code above will connect with our local Kernel and execute the command.
We can also pass an argument to point the location of the Mathematica Kernel as well with

```
WolframLanguageSession('/path/to/the/wolframscript/kernel')
```

But how can we configure and call Mathematica running in another server? Let's say 10.0.0.1:31415?

I've seen that we have an option to use a [WSTPServer](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wstpserver.html), but I couldn't figure it out how to use it with the `wolframscript` Python library.

Also in the [WolframScript](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/program/wolframscript.html) documentation we have an option to use the argument `-wstpserver`.

So how could we put all of this together?

Comment: Won't be easy because the `wolframclient` package talks either to a _local_ kernel or to one in the Wolfram cloud. According to Wolfram's WSTP page, there are bindings only for C/C++, Java and .NET, for other languages "it's in development". Don't hold your breath, though. One solution could be to write a Python web server that talks to a local Wolfram kernel using  the `wolframclient` package and then you'd access that Python server remotely over HTTP.

Comment: Oh, and if you go for the HTTP service: be mindful of the Wolfram license conditions , see e.g. `https://www.wolfram.com/engine/faq/` . They even consider in-house web access "commercial use".